Use the Global Accelorator for Websites with Users from other regions?
Suppose my application is in us-east-1 with tier db and web framework django. The application is serving dynamic content, which needs to be always up to date.
Some users are from australia and from south america with latency problems. Is a use case to use global accelerator in order to meet the latency problems?

Yes, Global Accelerator should be faster than going across the public Internet. However, there are limits to the speed you can obtain with international traffic. Australia is 15,000km from us-east-1. According to Home | CloudPing - AWS Latency Monitoring there is 200ms latency between ap-southeast-2 and us-east-1. Add to that the time taken for your users to reach the AWS data center. You should try Global Accelerator and see whether it meets your latency requirements.
